# Asp.net dropdown get text not value from options

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application in which I have a form which the user have to choose an option
in a dropdownlist before submitting (an Ajax call to a method in a controller).

When submitting, I want to be able to access the TEXT of the option, not the Value in the Controller.
How is this possible?

This is what the code in the View looks like:

```
<select name="adressID" id=" adressID ">
          <option>Choose Adress</option>
           @foreach (var address in @Model.Address)
                    {
                        <option value="@address.ID">@Html.Raw(address.Name)</option>
                    }
</select>
```

/ElC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably a lot of different ways to solve this, but one approach is using Request Form collection and name property.

1. Create a hidden property in the form.

   ```
   <input type="hidden" id="AddressName" name="AddressName" />
   ```
2. Create a script, something like this

   ```
   function SetSelectedText(addressID) //function with parameter that takes in the ID of the dropdownlist
    {
      var selectedText = addressPageId.options[addressPageId.selectedIndex].innerHTML; //Looks up the innerHTML of the option, based on the selectedIndex
      document.getElementById("AddressName").value = selectedText; //Sets the hidden property to the text retrieved from innerHTML above
    }
   ```
3. Add a onchange event in the select tag which invokes the function created and pass the id.

   ```
   onchange="SetSelectedText(this)"
   ```
4. In the controller should now be able to access the text of the option by using

   ```
   string textFromOption = Request.Form["AddressName"];
   ```

Hope this helps.
/ChrisRun

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever fires your form's submission (button click event?) to grab the selected option's text value and pass that along with the rest of the posted data. Here's how to do that via jQuery:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    var selectedText = $('#addressID option:selected').text();
    // pass with other values
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Razor, why don't you use the following?

```
@Html.DropDownList("AddressName", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Then in your controller on the GET use :

```
ViewBag.AddressName= new SelectList(db.Address, "Name", "Name");
```